# Test if a given control sequence is an \outer macro

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3

I'm in need of a macro which receives a control sequence as argument to test if this control sequence is actually an `\outer` macro. I can code it myself as below .

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\; } { `\: }
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\Z } { `\t }
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\T } { `\T }
\char_set_lccode:nn { `\F } { `\F }
\tl_map_function:nN { O U Z E R M A C R ; } \char_set_catcode_other:N
\tl_to_lowercase:n
  {
    \group_end:
    \prg_new_conditional:Nnn \cs_if_outer_macro:c { p, T , F , TF }
      {
        \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \cs_if_outer_macro_aux:w
        \cs_meaning:c {#1} OUZER ~ MACRO ; \q_stop
      }
    \cs_new_nopar:Npn \cs_if_outer_macro_aux:w #1 OUZER ~ MACRO ; #2 \q_stop
      {
        \prg_case_str:xxn { #1 ~ }
          {
            { \token_to_str:N \ }
            { \prg_return_true: }
            { \token_to_str:N \long \token_to_str:N \ }
            { \prg_return_true: }
            { \token_to_str:N \protected \token_to_str:N \ }
            { \prg_return_true: }
            { \token_to_str:N \protected \token_to_str:N \long \token_to_str:N \ }
            { \prg_return_true: }
          }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \IfOuterMacroTF \cs_if_outer_macro:cTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\long\outer\protected\def\fooa{}
\outer\def\foob{}
\def\fooc{}
\def\food{outer macro:}

\typeout{It's \IfOuterMacroTF{fooa}{}{NOT }an outer macro.}
\typeout{It's \IfOuterMacroTF{foob}{}{NOT }an outer macro.}
\typeout{It's \IfOuterMacroTF{fooc}{}{NOT }an outer macro.}
\typeout{It's \IfOuterMacroTF{food}{}{NOT }an outer macro.}
\typeout{It's \IfOuterMacroTF{relax}{}{NOT }an outer macro.}
```

It is inspired by the `l3token` package. The test is expandable.  I have used it in the `xeCJK` package. But, it only receives the *csname* instead of control sequence. What is more, I think it is a bit slow.

I think it is a good question and like to see other possible approaches.

Comment: A macro cannot receive an outer token as an argument: TeX will raise an error.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I meant you can't do `\outer\def\foo{}\def\baz#1{}\baz\foo`, _i.e._ pass an outer token as an argument.

Comment: @QingLee: for completeness about `\outer` tokens, you also have to be careful about `\foo` defined by `\halign{#\cr\global\futurelet\foo\relax\cr}`.  Its `\meaning` is `\outer endtemplate:` and it indeed is outer.

Answer (score 5):

This is not expandable, but maybe the test can be modified to be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \isouter { \exp_after:wN \checkouter:w \token_to_meaning:N }
\cs_new:Npn \checkouter:w #1 \relax
  {
   \regex_match:nnTF { outer .* macro .* :-> } { #1 } 
    { \typeout{OUTER~MACRO} } 
    { \typeout{NON~OUTER~TOKEN} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\outer\def\bye{bye}

\isouter\bye\relax

\stop
```

However this test can't be used in arguments to other macros, because of the rule mentioned by Joseph Wright.

Comment: Thakns! But the test will be true when `\def\bye{outer macro:->}`.

Comment: @QingLee Yes: I don't think one can do much about this.

Comment: does Bruno support ^ to anchor the regexp to start of string, in which case you could use that as the trick case would have meaning `macro:->outer macro`....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes.